# Checkbox-cli suite selection empty

Tags: checkbox

I am running a new install of Ubuntu 18.10. I have installed checkbox with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install checkbox-ng`

According to the instructions [here](https://checkbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#checkbox-command-line) after typing  `checkbox-cli` in a terminal I should see a list of options, but all I see is an "OK" tag. If I click on the "OK" tag I see the warning

> No testplan selected, aborting

Any ideas of what I am missing here?